# How can I configure PAM to do a simple LDAP authentication against an Active Directory server, without having to join the Ubuntu 16.04 VM to a domain?

Tags: login, authentication, ldap, pam, active-directory

I'm using Vagrant and some ansible scripts to provision an Ubuntu 16.04 server image on my Windows 10 computer that is joined to a domain. I want to log into the VM using the same credentials as I log into the Windows 10 computer, however, I don't have permissions on the domain to join the VM to it (and also, I want to be able to destroy and rebuild the VM on a whim, and not need to keep jumping through hoops to join it).

Ideally, I "just" want to do an LDAP authentication attempt to login to the box, but I don't know how to do it with the ldap-auth-client?

I have read articles such as [LDAPClientAuthentication | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication) and [SingleSignOn | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn) but both of these assume you'll be integrating into the AD, whereas I'm just looking for an LDAP lookup.